# Using If/Then Statement in ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, attribute-table

I am trying to add a column that shows vegetation production (numeric) in relation to soil series. I have each soil series already in the attribute table however I am having a hard time writing the if/then statement to say something along the lines of "If soil series is "vc" Then production should be 2500". Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: I tried that and didn't help. Not sure how to add another photo to these comment box

Comment: If [SoilSeries] =Ga Then
 [UF_Prod]="2055"

Comment: The first related question shows the proper implementation of if/then in the field calculator for both VBscript and Python

Comment: Please always provide code as formatted text rather than pictures.

Comment: @BERA you're responses are unwelcoming and harsh.  VB Script, although perhaps not the default, is perfectly acceptable; in fact, your "help section" link takes the reader to VB Script help! Ironic, eh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the `UF_Prod` field, go to Field calculator, select `Parser: Python`, check `Show Codeblock`, and write the following python code:

```
def prod(s,p):
    if s == 'Ga':
        return 2100 # change this value as required
    elif s == 'Gc':
        return 2200 # change this value as required
    elif s == 'Ha':
        return 2300 # change this value as required
    elif s == 'vc':
        return 2500 # change this value as required
    else:
        return 0 # change this value as required
```

UF_Prod:

```
prod( !SoilSeries! , !UF_Prod! )
```

Change the soil names and the production values as you like, the above code is just a sample. You need to modify it based on what soil names you have in the attribute table and based on the production value the you want for each soil name.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am new at coding, I'll be using this site to learn! Thanks!